# solr 4.8 - indexing and searching large files back to back

Tags: solr

we use solr 4.8 with one stored field and 2 indexed fields,using 4GB RAM we are able to index and search files with size upto 200MB, but files above 200MB size gives OOM error. Is this as expected? How to calculate the amount of RAM needed to index and search large files?

Edit: i tried by allocation the JVM 20GB but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer which solve using master slave replication  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784546/solr-indexing-issue-out-of-memory-looking-for-a-solution).

or else

You can increase the jvm size when staring solr as

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar start.jar
```

Comment: we have already tried this solution, our problem is to know max heap size that should be set, as the size of document being indexed is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Estimate sizes in Solr is not an easy task.

You can try using [this](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/20f9303f5e2378e2238a5381291414881ddb8172/dev-tools/size-estimator-lucene-solr.xls)

Comment: ok let me try with this calculation.One more thing is searching 200mb file with maxanalyzedchars=-1 is always failing with the above mentioned settings.Below is the error seen[impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient]  - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
2014-11-26 10:49:22,659 [dlpCheckTaskExecutor-1] INFO [impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient]  - Retrying request i want this property to be set as i want the whole file to be analyzed while highlighting.please let me know if you have any solution.